# How can I get form data from a div tag by using its class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, frontend

I have code something like:

```js
var iconContainer = document.getElementById('iconContainer');
var icon = iconContainer.getElementsByClassName("item");

for (var i = 0; i < icon.length; i++) {
  icon[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";

  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  <header>
    <div class="icon-line" id="iconContainer">
      <div class="item active" id="">
        <div class="group-icon">
          <i class="fas fa-hdd"></i>
        </div>
        <span>SSD</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item" id="">
        <div class="group-icon">
          <i class="fas fa-server"></i>
        </div>
        <span>EKRAN KARTI</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item" id="">
        <div class="group-icon">
          <i class="fas fa-microchip"></i>
        </div>
        <span>İŞLEMCİ</span>
      </div>

      <div class="item" id="">
        <div class="group-icon">
          <i class="fas fa-memory"></i>
        </div>
        <span>RAM</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</form>
```

Also I have a selection.js that changes selected item's class from class="item" to class="item-active"

How can controll the selected item by using it's data?

I want to search in my data by using selected item. For exapmle, you selected SSD, so that, I will search on my SSD.json file or you selected RAM, I will search on my ram.js

How can do this?

*Note: I'm using Node.js on server side.*

Comment: So you will want to do a search request to the server with params is the value of the selected item. You'll trigger this on click event on item.

Comment: @thanhdx yes, excatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, firstly you have a `for` loop that change item's class to "active" one, we will continue adding code there.

```
var iconContainer = document.getElementById('iconContainer');
var icon = iconContainer.getElementsByClassName("item");

for (var i = 0; i < icon.length; i++) {
  icon[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
    // ADD CODE HERE

  });
}
```

You'll have to do 2 things: get the selected item's value and send it to server by making a searh request with the value as params.

Get the selected item's value by getting the 's innerText:

```
...
// ADD CODE HERE
var value = this.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerText;
```

And make a get request with the value with `fetch` API (or any libs that support make xhr request):

```
...
// ADD CODE HERE
var value = this.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerText;
fetch(`URL_TO_SERVER/?params=${value}`)
   .then(res => {
        // do what you want with search result
   }
```

The rest is your server's work to handle the request, take params, search on respective file and return the search result to client.

That's all.

In better way, instead of using value from `innerText` as param, you should use `data-attribute` for better request. You can read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: thank you so much! It worked, now i can write to console my selected item. I want to use it for searching on my json datas, but i want to do it when user press the "Search" button. Do you have any suggestion? or any resource  ?  If you can help me, i can explain detailed, actually, i don't know any web programming language, just learning for my project.

Comment: @quality38 You'll need to create a button, handle button's click event, get the active item's value, and do request. I have a pen here: https://codepen.io/Thanhxd/pen/bGdNGbp